# Show that a function which has a unique right inverse is necessarily bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, elementary-functions

I try to prove a problem

> Show that a function which has a unique right inverse is necessarily bijective.

I proved it is surjective, but I can not prove it is injective to finish the proof. I need help. Thank all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f:X\to Y$ is a function then function $g:Y\to X$ will serve as a right-inverse for $f$ if and only if $$\forall y\in Y \left[g(y)\in f^{-1}(\{y\})\right]$$

(Note that $g(y)\in f^{-1}(\{y\}$ and $g(f(y))=y$ are equivalent statements.)

So condition for existence of a right-inverse is that the sets $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ are not empty (i.e. $f$ must be surjective) and condition for a *unique* right-inverse is that moreover these sets are singletons (so $f$ must be injective).

Comment: Sorry, I’m afraid I don’t quite understand. Could you explain to me?

Comment: Do you understand that $g(y)\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$ means actually the same as $f(g(y))=y$? If this is true for every $y\in Y$ then $g$ is a right-inverse for $f$. Here $f^{-1}(\{y\}):=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=y\}$. This set (preimage of singleton) is a so-called fiber of $f$.

Comment: Sincerely thanks. Now I really know it.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the function $f$ is not injective. Then there are two different values $x \neq y$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$. How can you construct two different right inverses in this case, contradicting the uniqueness?